# Files not getting Downloaded in Spring

Tags: java, ajax, spring

There  is a  page where i have files list. On cliking on any of the .txt it must get downloaded and a notification should be displayed as the notification we get in download anything on GoogleChrome.

This is my Js which is called after cliking on .txt files
Here i am doing is, i am getting the filename and the filepath of the selected file. And then using ajax sending those filename and filepath to the spring servlet.

```
if (options.downloadable) {
  $(easyTree).find('.easy-tree-toolbar').append('<div class="fileDownload"><button class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-down"></span></button></div>');
  $(easyTree).find('.easy-tree-toolbar .fileDownload > button').attr('title', options.i18n.downloadTip).click(function() {
    var selected = getSelectedItems();
    var fileName = $(selected).find(' > span > a').text();
    alert("fileName**" + fileName);
    var hrefValue = $(selected).find(' > span > a').attr('href');
    alert("hrefValue**" + hrefValue);
    if (selected.length <= 0) {
      $(easyTree).prepend(warningAlert);
      $(easyTree).find('.alert .alert-content').html(options.i18n.downloadNull);
    } else {
      $.ajax({
        url: "/ComplianceApplication/downloadFileFromDirectory",
        type: "GET",
        data: {
          hrefValue: hrefValue,
          fileName: fileName
        },
        success: function(data) {

          //$(selected).remove();
          //window.location.reload();
        },
        error: function(e) {

        }
      });

    }
  });
}
```

This is my springController. Here I am getting all the data properly but the problem is file is not getting downloaded and am not even getting any error so that I can come to know what mistake I am doing.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/downloadFileFromDirectory",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public  @ResponseBody void downloadFileFromDirectory(@PathVariable("fileName") String fileName,@RequestParam(value = "hrefValue") String hrefValue,HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,Model model){
        System.out.println("hrefValue***"+hrefValue);

       String filePath = hrefValue;
        ServletContext context = request.getSession().getServletContext();
        File downloadFile = new File(filePath);
        FileInputStream inputStream = null;
        OutputStream outStream = null;
        try {
            inputStream = new FileInputStream(downloadFile);
            response.setContentLength((int) downloadFile.length());
            response.setContentType(context.getMimeType(downloadFile.getName()));
            // response header
            String headerKey = "Content-Disposition";
            String headerValue = String.format("attachment; filename=\"%s\"", downloadFile.getName());
            //String headerValue = String.format("attachment; filename=\"%s\"", downloadFile.getName());
            response.setHeader(headerKey, headerValue);
            // Write response
            outStream = response.getOutputStream();
            IOUtils.copy(inputStream, outStream);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (null != inputStream)
                    inputStream.close();
                if (null != outStream)
                    outStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
 }
```

Any suggestions ???

Comment: I normally use response.flushBuffer(); after copying the stream

Comment: If you put the file URL in your browser the file is downloaded ?

Comment: @reos After putting the url in browser directly the file gets open.

Comment: @Vincent  even used response.flushBuffer(); after copying the stream but still its not working

Comment: I think you have to see this for ajax file download  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545311/download-a-file-by-jquery-ajax

Answer (score 0):

I usually use this kind of code with no problem:

```
public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> downloadFile(@PathVariable("idForm") String idForm)
{
    try
    {

            File parent = new File(csvFilesPath);
            File file = new File(parent, idForm+".csv");
            HttpHeaders respHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
            MediaType mediaType = new MediaType("text","csv");
            respHeaders.setContentType(mediaType);
            respHeaders.setContentLength(file.length());
            respHeaders.setContentDispositionFormData("attachment", "file.csv");
            InputStreamResource isr = new InputStreamResource(new FileInputStream(file));
            return new ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource>(isr, respHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
        }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        String message = "Errore nel download del file "+idForm+".csv; "+e.getMessage();
        logger.error(message, e);
        return new ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource>(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem it's in you ajax code, so you can use JQuery File Download.

It's as simple as

```
$.fileDownload('/url/to/download.pdf');
```

Here you can see a tutorial

http://johnculviner.com/jquery-file-download-plugin-for-ajax-like-feature-rich-file-downloads/